Generate, for a given number of variables, all expression post-absorption that use only conjunction and disjunction with no permutation
I learned the law of absorption in Boolean algebra and asked myself how to generate, for a given number of variables, all expression post-absorption that use only conjunction and disjunction with no permutation. Below is an informal description of the problem I came up with. I would like to know this problem formal name/description and what are the most efficient solutions.
Informal description:
For a given number of different letters (example: 5 letters: {a,b,c,d,e} ),
Build all possible sentences following these rules:

In words, letters are commutative.
Example: The word "abc" is no different than "acb", "bac", "bca", "cab", "cba".

Each letter can be used once or zero time per word.
So, a word can be made of a single letter.

In a sentence, words are commutative.

In a sentence, a word does not contain another one.
More precisely: a word cannot be written entirely with some or all letters of one other word.

You add words until you cannot (saturation).
Example of a saturated sentence using 5 different letters: "abcd abe ce de"

No permutations.
Example: "abce abd cd ed" is a permutation of "abcd abe ce de" (we just inversed the e and d).
So, we do not generate them both.


Result example:
All sentences using 4 different letters:
abcd
abc d
ab c d
a b c d
ab ac bc d
abc abd cd
abc ad bd cd
abc abd acd bcd
ab ac ad bc bd cd

What you are calling a sentence is a maximal Sperner family (up to permutation of the element names).

Thanks @Karl, I will look at that. I see that there are formulas describing the size of those things; do you know if it implies an efficient way to generate the specific result in my question for higher number of letters, or on the contrary if the algorithm would need a lots of trial and error, even if we let go the no permutation criteria ?

I think there's an algorithm to generate the maximal Sperner families with runtime proportional to the number of results, but this could still be impractical just because the number of results is very large. Avoiding the permuted duplicates might be hard without generating them and applying the permutations. This all seems like a fun programming exercise.

Here is an implementation of an algorithm that generates antichains in an arbitrary DAG.
